# C++ how to make the user not repeat numbers

Tags: arrays, loops, visual-c++

I need to make a program for a LoShu Magic Square. The User has to input the numbers 1-9, into the array, but they cannot repeat any of the numbers. I have tried using multiple while loops, but that didn't work completely. How would I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. define a vector to hold  the entered data by the user ( initially it will be empty)
2. use a do while loop as follow

do{
 // get the user input 
 }while(condition)  // test if the entred data is in the vector, if it is not exit the loop
// after exitting the loop add the element to the vector

This will ensure that the user want enter a number already exists in the vector.
If you want the user to enter multiple numbers just add a uper while loop (infinite loop)